# Хочу сделать полиморфизм (на сколько я это понимаю) но что то не получается пишет нужно поставить super() но он мне не нужен ибо у меня есть свой мет

Tags: javascript, ооп

[image: план]

```
class Car {
    constructor ( clasAouto, engine, driver, marka ) {
        this.clasAouto = clasAouto;
        this.engine = engine;
        this.driver = driver;
        this.marka = marka;
    }
    start() {
        console.log(`${this.driver} поехали  на ${this.marka}`)
    }
    stop() {
        console.log(`${this.driver} остановился на машине ${this.marka}`)
    }
    turnRight() {
        console.log(`${this.driver} повернул на право`)
    }
    turnLeft() {
        console.log(`${this.driver} повернул на лево`)
    }
    toString() {
        console.log(`У ${this.driver} есть машина классом ${this.clasAouto} модель ${this.marka} у нее ${this.engine} двигатель `);
    }
}
let car = new Car("Sedan", "Benzin", "Geri", "Toyota");
car.start();
car.stop();
car.turnRight();
car.turnLeft();
car.toString();

class Driver extends Car {
    constructor(exp) {
        this.exp = exp;   
    }
    name(surName, firstName, twoName) {
        console.log(`${surName} ${firstName} ${twoName} опыт ${this.exp}`);
    }
    toString() {
        super.toString();
        this.name();
    }
}
let driver = new Driver("27");
driver.toString();
```

Comment: Какой тогда смысл наследование от класса, если методы родителя не нужны? И как то странно, что водитель наследуется от машины...

Comment: такое задание (я могу не понимать задачу ибо только 2 дня изучаю ООП)

Comment: так приведите задание-то? очевидно, как написано выше, наследовать водителя от машины не надо

Comment: Создать класс Car , Engine и Driver
Класс Driver содержит поля - ФИО, стаж вождения.
Класс Engine содержит поля - мощность, производитель.
Класс Car содержит поля - марка автомобиля, класс автомобиля, вес, водитель типа Driver, мотор типа Engine. Методы start(), stop(), turnRight(), turnLeft(), которые выводят на печать: "Поехали", "Останавливаемся", "Поворот направо" или "Поворот налево". А также метод toString(), который выводит полную информацию об автомобиле, ее водителе и моторе.

Comment: Может [это ответ на ваш вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1489435/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%a7%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8e-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%86%d0%b0/1489448#1489448)?

Comment: сват ты прав что должен быть persen  и от него я должен тянуть метод

Comment: Что бы обратиться к конкретному человеку, поставьте @ и введите его ник. Тогда даже уведомление приходит

Comment: Ну добавьте картинку к вопросу...

Comment: Ну похоже, что да. Driver должен наследоваться от Person. Остальные классы должны передаваться в Car как указано в ссылке выше. + метод toString() у вас должен возвращать строку, согласно примеру,  а он у вас ничего не возвращает

Comment: спасибо сейчас буду пробовать что то исправлять ибо я даже не очень понимал что эти стрелки означают то

Comment: Стрелка с направлением - от кого наследоваться(стрелка от кого). Стрелки с обозначением 1-1 это что то вроде обозначения, что одному car может быть присвоено одно значение водителя и двигателя.

Comment: class Driver extends Person {
    constructor(exp) {
        this.exp = exp;   
    }
    toString() {
        super.toString("Der", "Dgert", "Senf");
    }
}
let driver = new Driver("27");
Uncaught ReferenceError: невозможно получить доступ к «Person» перед инициализацией. Класс "Person" создан

Comment: Видимо класс Person описан ниже класса Driver )

Comment: точно кстати куда "super" 
class Driver extends Person {
    constructor(exp) {
        this.exp = exp;   
    }
    toString() {
        super.toString("Der", "Dgert", "Senf");
    }
}
let driver = new Driver("27"); стоит так но ему чет не нрав Uncaught ReferenceError: необходимо вызвать суперконструктор в производном классе перед доступом к «этому» или возвратом из производного конструктора
     в новом драйвере (js.js:130:9)
     на js.js:136:14

Comment: в задаче нет вообще ничего про наследование. Сказано четко, сделать три класса. Авто должно содержать информацию о двигателе и водителе. Не надо придумывать лишнее.

Comment: Может этот ответ поможет вам [разобраться в super()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1492783/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4)